# Is it possible to force jQuery to make AJAX calls for URLs with gzip/deflate enabled?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, gzip, deflate

I have a web service that is willing to output gzip/deflated data.  I've verified that the service will respond with raw JSON or with gzip'd JSON using wget and curl.

I want to consume this web service using the jQuery AJAX call.

By default, the $.ajax call that jQuery provides does not add the "Accept-Encoding: gzip" HTTP request header that's necessary for the web server to respond with gzipped data.

However, when I use jQuery's own methods to add the header, eg:

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://foo.com/service.json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
            console.log('xhr set'); 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'deflate') 
       } 
});
```

then the following error appears in the browser console:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"
```

Is it possible to force jQuery to make AJAX calls for URLs with gzip/deflate enabled?

If not, is this a shortcoming in jQuery, or something more fundamental with AJAX?

Comment: I think the browser decides wether it accepts gzip/deflate or not. "Faking" this could lead to data corruption.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Browsers automatically add the accept-encoding header as appropriate, including on XHR requests.  You don't need to do that at the DOM/JS level.

Comment: thanks, you're right! I should have checked my server logs more closely.

Comment: Is this true for HTML5 Hybrid applications also? Running on mobile devices, in a webview container....?

Comment: @demaniak: It should be, yes. Are you seeing different behavior in a particular webview?

Comment: @DaveWard - I suspect Android 4.3 webview (on the admittedly custom device) I am working on might not have been adding Accept-Encoding headers. However, I will try to verify this first ;) Any tips apart from Weinre to examine what is happening under the hood? Assume I can't access the backend server to examine incoming requests there.

Comment: @demaniak: I would probably proxy the Android device through Fiddler (or Charles on a Mac) on my local machine (e.g. http://encosia.com/using-an-iphone-with-the-visual-studio-development-server/) to inspect the real traffic.