# How to add custom header to browser request

Tags: javascript, browser, http-headers

I'm trying to set `Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0` in http request.

while I'm trying to set this in my code, it shows,

> Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"

Can anyone tell me why I'm not able to set header in http request?.

Is there any way to set this header?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778706/is-it-possible-to-force-jquery-to-make-ajax-calls-for-urls-with-gzip-deflate-ena

Comment: I'm doing this to disable gzip compression in browser.