# How to Gzip a json file and read it from server?

Tags: json, gzip

can anybody explain the process. I am totally confused. NO idea of how to get this compression and decompression. Detail guide will be appreciated, However please leave your thoughts and suggestion which are useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force jQuery to make AJAX calls for URLs with gzip/deflate enabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778706/is-it-possible-to-force-jquery-to-make-ajax-calls-for-urls-with-gzip-deflate-ena)

Comment: NO i am asking what is gzip and how to do things. i have not even included ajax or jquery here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question explicitly asked "How to Gzip a json file and read it from server?", not "what is gzip and how to do things"

### The link actually have an answer marked

> Browsers automatically add the accept-encoding header as appropriate,
>   including on XHR requests. You don't need to do that at the DOM/JS
>   level.

If you need detailed step by step:

- Choose a mature web server (IIS, apache)
- Create a directory
- Put your json into a file with .json file extension
- Make sure the MIME type is set, if you are using IIS check it out [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx)

Gzip/deflate is done by the web server & almost all browsers. You do **not** have to do anything.

If you are generating dynamic json content as opposed to the above steps (static), just make sure your application is sending the mime type properly and let the browser do it.

Comment: I need detailed step only. Thanks and i have a doubt? the browser will automatically decompress the file received from server?

Comment: Yes, if you have doubt, try using fiddler to see what exactly is being sent over the wire